# Why is my FontAwesome content appearing off center as a background?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to set a FontAwesome icon as a "defualt thumbnail" for a list of articles.  My problem is that the icon is appearing off center horizontally in my div.  See the [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ev8j3c5c/).

```
<div class="card-row-image fa fa-cutlery thumbnail-default">
   <div class="card-row-label"><a href="http://mahanap.dev/index.php/categories/restaurants">Restaurants</a>
   </div>
   <div class="card-row-price">Pennsylvania</div>
</div>

.thumbnail-default {
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px solid #547b97;
  background: #e4e4e4;
}
.thumbnail-default:before {
    position:absolute;
    font-family: 'FontAwesome';
    font-size: 72px;
    color: #547b97;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
}
.card-row-price {
  background-color: #009f8b;
  bottom: 0px;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 13px;
  left: 50%;
  padding: 3px 15px;
  position: absolute;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%);
  white-space: nowrap;
  z-index: 2; 
}
.card-row-label {
  background-color: #c6af5c;
  color: #fff;
  left: 50%;
  font-size: 13px;
  padding: 3px 15px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%);
  z-index: 2; 
}
.card-row-image {
  background-position: center center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  height: 200px;
  position: relative;
  width: 262px; }
```

Here is my current output:

[image]

Any ideas?  Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

set these css codes to make it centered. This happens because on absolute positioned pseudo elements, if you do not specify where to be horizontally (you did not set `left` or `right` property), it will follow the text flow and would obey the `text-align: center` set on the parent.

```
.thumbnail-default:before { left: 50%; transform: translate(-50%, -50%); }
```

[Working Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ev8j3c5c/2/)

Comment: I think stack Overflow runs with an assumption that a tick isn't allowed until enough time has elapsed to encourage multiple answers

Comment: the problem is that there is only a limited correlaton between `time` and `amount of good answers` (combined, giving the `probability of good answer appearing`) , the best answer to a question may not appear until a day later, depending on the popularity of the question. Anyhow, this is an aside and entirely offtopic!

Comment: I almost forgot!  Stupid time limit... Lol.